# Get all 4-lettered words Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

To get all 4 lettered words delimited by any  I have written the following code:

```js
function select() {
    var html = document.getElementById('p').innerHTML;
 var fourLettered = html.match(/[^a-zA-Z|^$][a-zA-Z]{4}[^a-zA-Z|^$]/g) || [];
 document.getElementById('other').innerHTML = fourLettered.join('<br>');
}
```

```css
p {
 background-color: #eee;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p id="p" contenteditable="true">This is <i>a</i> <span class="red">paragraph</span> <b>with</b> lots of markup and-lots-of letters;with?four char</p>
<p id="other"></p>
<button onclick="select()">SELECT</button>
```

However, I am unable to get the 4 letter words at the start or end of the p tag i.e. `This` & `char` in this case.

Also the markup /span> is getting selected.
How can this problem be solved?

Comment: What about words delimited by `-`? See my answer below, as I have updated it.

Comment: @timolawl, better point to http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for new users.

Comment: @NinaScholz Thanks for the information. This is helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function select() {
    var html = document.getElementById('p').textContent;
 var fourLettered = html.match(/\b[a-zA-Z]{4}\b/g) || [];
 document.getElementById('other').innerHTML = fourLettered.join('<br>');
}
```

```css
p {
 background-color: #eee;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p id="p" contenteditable="true">This is <i>a</i> <span class="red">paragraph</span> <b>with</b> lots of markup and-lots-of letters;with?four char</p>
<p id="other"></p>
<button onclick="select()">SELECT</button>
```